# How can I change the text font size of a TListviewItem?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a TListView.

```
lwadattarolas: TListView;
egylistviewitem:tlistviewitem;
```

I added an item to TListView:

```
  egylistviewitem:=lwadattarolas.Items.Add;
  egylistviewitem.Text:='Test';
```

How can I change the size of font of tlistviewitem?
In the objectinspector I can to change details1,details2,details3 font size but I can't to change the text font size.

Comment: FMX or VCL? If the former, what is the target platform?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have found the answer! I hope you will like it.

"In fact with a small modification to the unit MultiDetailAppearanceU.pas namely simply republishing the Text property of the class TMultiDetailItemAppearance and recompiling the package SampleListViewMultiDetailAppearancePackage, we get back the Text node (in this ItemAppearance standard):"

Comment: Please don't post off site links. This link will likely go stale in due course. Post enough details in the answer to explain how to solve this. -1

Comment: @LionKing - thanks for posting an answer when you found it (that's good) - but please post the actual answer here, so that people can read it here. Links die over time as websites change, so there needs to be a full answer on this site.